# Another Number Sequence...Yayy!

Tags: number-sequence

Find the next terms and also, explain the logic used for the terms of the sequence.

$3,7,11,15,20,27,?????$

Hint : Autobots, This is Optimus Prime.

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it.  (That indicates what the correct answer is, so there's no doubt; it also awards the successful answerer for their effort, and as an added bonus, gives you +2 rep for doing it! It's also just good etiquette for this site. You have a few questions right now that seem to have good answers, and none have been accepted; please consider doing so. Thanks!)

Answer (score 3):

I think that the next term is

> $33$

Reasoning

> Let $p_n$ be the sequence of prime numbers: $2,3,5,7,11,13,17, \ldots$ 
>  Let $q_n$ be the sequence of positive non-prime numbers composed solely of positive non-prime digits: $1,4,6,8,9,14,16,\ldots$ 
>  The $n$th term of the sequence above  is $p_n + q_n$ which makes the $7$th term $p_7 + q_7 = 17 + 16 = 33$

Comment: how does this fit with the hint?

Comment: I think the hint is meant to refer to these http://oeis.org/A217090, you might want to see if that clarifies your solution at all.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Really I just honed in on the word prime, not sure how autobots come into it.